# the table is on the right side how I can fix it

Tags: tables, size

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c||c||c|} 
\hline
 Scheme & Architecture & Functionality \\
\hline
Intelligent wall & Active frequency selective surfaces with PIN diodes & Fully transparent reflecting surfaces\\
Spatial microwave modulators & Binary phase state tunable meta-surfaces & Shaping complex microwave fields\\
Coding meta-materials & Meta-surfaces with binary elements (0 or $\pi$ phases) & Reconfigurable scattering patterns\\
Programmable meta-surface & Meta-surfaces with PIN diode-equipped cells & Reconfigurable phase, polarization,
and scattering\\
Reconfigurable reflect-arrays & Reflect-arrays with tunable (varactor-tuned) resonators & Adjustable reflection phase\\
Large intelligent surface & Active contiguous surface for transmission and reception & Gains compared to massive MIMO   \\
Software-controlled hypersurface & Meta-surfaces equipped with IoT gateways & Wave absorption, polarization,
and steering\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}\\ \\
```

Comment: Tabularx without any X type column does not really make sense. You may want to try replacing the  c column type with X column types.

Comment: I tried it, did not work

Comment: What exactly does "did not work" mean? Do you end up with a code that is not compilable, does the table still protrude into the right margin or do you end up with a table that fits but you just don't like the look of it?

Comment: Please also make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. (See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: the table still in right side

Comment: "on right side" or "in right side" doesn't really make sense.  I think you mean "is going too far to the right" or "protrudes into the right margin".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C||C||C|} 
\hline
 Scheme & Architecture & Functionality \\
\hline
Intelligent wall & Active frequency selective surfaces with PIN diodes & Fully transparent reflecting surfaces\\
Spatial microwave modulators & Binary phase state tunable meta-surfaces & Shaping complex microwave fields\\
Coding meta-materials & Meta-surfaces with binary elements (0 or $\pi$ phases) & Reconfigurable scattering patterns\\
Programmable meta-surface & Meta-surfaces with PIN diode-equipped cells & Reconfigurable phase, polarization, and scattering\\
Reconfigurable reflect-arrays & Reflect-arrays with tunable (varactor-tuned) resonators & Adjustable reflection phase\\
Large intelligent surface & Active contiguous surface for transmission and reception & Gains compared to massive MIMO   \\
Software-controlled hypersurface & Meta-surfaces equipped with IoT gateways & Wave absorption, polarization, and steering\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```